# Painting filled ellipse with Pyside

Tags: python, pyside

I'm trying to paint an solid colored ellipse in pyside and I'm getting an unexpected black line around the outside and I'm also not getting what appears to be a smooth circular shape? Some colors are not showing up as well.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(200, 50)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ui_list = QtGui.QComboBox()
        grid = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.ui_list)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.populate_list()

    def populate_list(self):
        colors = {
            'White': QtCore.Qt.white,  
            'Black': QtCore.Qt.black,  
            'Red': QtCore.Qt.red,
            'Green': QtCore.Qt.green,   
            'Blue': QtCore.Qt.blue,
            'Cyan': QtCore.Qt.cyan,
            'Magenta': QtCore.Qt.magenta,
            'Yellow': QtCore.Qt.yellow, 
            'Gray': QtCore.Qt.gray,
            'Orange': QtGui.QColor(255,128,0)
        }
        px = QtGui.QPixmap(12,12)

        for key, val in sorted(colors.items()):
            px.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(px)
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(val))
            painter.drawEllipse(0,0,12,12)
            self.ui_list.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(px), key) 

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the approved answer, It looks to me like the outline is black and setting a larger pixmap is making the issue less visible. I would be better to set the stroke color instead. Also, making a pixmap larger in order to get a nicer looking circle is unnecessary if you turn on antialiasing explicitly.

...

```
for key, val in sorted(colors.items()):
    # a small pixmap size
    size = 32
    px = QtGui.QPixmap(size,size)
    px.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(px)
    # turn on Antialiasing
    painter.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
    # set the brush and pen to the same color
    painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(val))
    painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor(val))
    painter.drawEllipse(px.rect())
    painter.end()
    self.ui_list.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(px), key)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a larger `QPixmap`, besides that you must call `painter.end()` to indicate that you must finish painting:

```
class Example(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(200, 50)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.ui_list = QtGui.QComboBox()
        grid = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.ui_list)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.populate_list()

    def populate_list(self):
        colors = {
            'White': QtCore.Qt.white,  
            'Black': QtCore.Qt.black,  
            'Red': QtCore.Qt.red,
            'Green': QtCore.Qt.green,   
            'Blue': QtCore.Qt.blue,
            'Cyan': QtCore.Qt.cyan,
            'Magenta': QtCore.Qt.magenta,
            'Yellow': QtCore.Qt.yellow, 
            'Gray': QtCore.Qt.gray,
            'Orange': QtGui.QColor(255,128,0)
        }
        px = QtGui.QPixmap(640,640)

        for key, val in sorted(colors.items()):
            px.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(px)
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(val))
            painter.drawEllipse(px.rect())
            painter.end()
            self.ui_list.addItem(QtGui.QIcon(px), key)
```

[image]